# Github /orgs/:org/repos returns "Repository offline" when authenticated

Tags: github, oauth, github-api

I'm trying to access the "/repos" endpoint of a github organization where I'm in the owners group using curl. The token I'm using here is a personal API token generated using the "settings" interface on Github.

Using this CURL command (some scrubbing "{}", of course).

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/orgs/{ORGNAME by text}/repos\?access_token\={TOKEN}
```

I get this response:

```
{
  "message": "Repository offline",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

Here are the headers (by using the same command + "-i")

```
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Server: GitHub.com
Date: {date}
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 96
Status: 503 Service Unavailable
X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 4998
X-RateLimit-Reset: {msec}
X-OAuth-Scopes: admin:org, gist, notifications, read:public_key, read:repo_hook, repo, user
X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes: repo
X-GitHub-Media-Type: github.v3
Link: <https://api.github.com/organizations/{7 digit number}/repos?access_token={TOKEN}&page=2>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/organizations/{7 digit number}/repos?access_token={TOKEN}&page=17>; rel="last"
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: deny
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

It seems really odd that it'd give me links to the next/last API calls along with a page number, and then return "Repository offline." In fact, the API calls they give actually work starting at page 2 and above, but not page 1, or with the "page" attribute unspecified.

I've also tried accessing the repos without auth using the same CURL command above minus the token. It returns the expected json: The one fully public repository in my organization.

I tried searching online for 503 response codes from Github API calls as well as the "repository offline" message but couldn't dig anything up. Why is the API call not working, nor the API call in their header at any page < 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. One of the repositories seems broken in the org. When I try to view it, I get a 500 error page. Now I have to figure out why I'm getting the 500.

Comment: If you already haven't, can you get in touch with GitHub support so that we can take a look? support@github.com

Comment: Someone submitted a ticket this morning. Apparently the repo has been broken for a few years now, and no one had trouble with it until I started trying to automate mass cloning using the API.